# Struct initialization depends on moving borrowed value

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to initialize a struct like the following:

```
struct UsbCommandPort<'a> {
    serial: SerialPort<'a, UsbBus<USB>>,
    usb_dev: UsbDevice<'a, UsbBus<USB>>,
}

impl UsbCommandPort<'_> {
    pub fn new() -> Self
    {
        let usb: USB = USB::new();
        let usb_bus: UsbBusAllocator<UsbBus<USB>> = UsbBus::new(usb);

        let serial:SerialPort<'_, UsbBus<USB>> = SerialPort::new(&usb_bus);

        let usb_dev:UsbDevice<'_, UsbBus<USB>> = UsbDeviceBuilder::new(&usb_bus, UsbVidPid(0x16c0, 0x27dd))
            .device_class(usbd_serial::USB_CLASS_CDC)
            .build();

        UsbCommandPort { 
            serial: serial, 
            usb_dev: usb_dev,
        }
    }
```

Both `SerialPort::new` and `UsbDeviceBuilder::new` take a *reference* to `usb_bus`.

This function fails to compile with the error

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `usb_bus`
```

This makes sense, as `usb_bus` will cease to exist when the function returns, and the references will be dangling.

To prevent this from happening, I'd like to transfer ownership of `usb_bus` to the struct. So I add it as as a member variable:

```
struct UsbCommandPort<'a> {
    usb_bus: UsbBusAllocator<UsbBus<USB>>,
    serial: SerialPort<'a, UsbBus<USB>>,
    usb_dev: UsbDevice<'a, UsbBus<USB>>,
}

impl UsbCommandPort<'_> {
    pub fn new() -> Self
    {
        let usb: USB = USB::new();
        let usb_bus: UsbBusAllocator<UsbBus<USB>> = UsbBus::new(usb);

        let serial:SerialPort<'_, UsbBus<USB>> = SerialPort::new(&usb_bus);

        let usb_dev:UsbDevice<'_, UsbBus<USB>> = UsbDeviceBuilder::new(&usb_bus, UsbVidPid(0x16c0, 0x27dd))
            .device_class(usbd_serial::USB_CLASS_CDC)
            .build();

        UsbCommandPort {
            usb_bus: usb_bus, 
            serial: serial, 
            usb_dev: usb_dev,
        }
    }
```

However this also fails to compile. The previous error is still there:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `usb_bus`
```

and now there is a new error:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `usb_bus` because it is borrowed
```

I cannot transfer ownership of `usb_bus` to the struct because it is already borrowed. However, I cannot create the struct without initializing `serial` and `usb_dev` which require the borrows.

Can I somehow incrementially initalize the struct, by first assigning `usb_bus`, then update it by assigning `serial` and `usb_dev` with references to the struct-owned `usb_bus`?